# Can't get internet data at android 4.0.4

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, null-pointer

I have a problem with my developed app for Android. 
I trying to get data from Google Translate API via JSON Parser. 
The application works perfectly on Emulator (v 2.1) and T-Mobile Move Balance (v 2.3.5)
The problem happens at Android 4.0.4 (device ZTE BLADE III). When I trying to get data, it returns *null pointer*( NullPointerException  which is surrounded by try-catch block). 
 
There is app permisions at the Manifest

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I think is error in Manifest or settings configuration on the device (already checked internet connection and works with other apps. Browser works also), because the app works fine in older versions. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I thought it isn't needed 
Here is the Activity with one button and two spinners, with listener at the button

```
  public class OptionsActivity extends Activity {

private String mSourceLanguage, mDestinationLanguage;
private Spinner sourceSpinner, destinationSpinner;
private  static ArrayList<Language> languages;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);

    sourceSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    destinationSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    updateSpinners();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_options, menu);
    return true;
}

// isprakjanje na informacii na jazicite do ManuaInputActivity
public void submitLanguages(View v){
    mSourceLanguage = sourceSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    mDestinationLanguage = destinationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String sourceCode = "", destCode = "";
    sourceCode = getCode(mSourceLanguage);
    destCode = getCode(mDestinationLanguage);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ManualInputActivity.class);

    Bundle spinnerBundle = new Bundle();
    spinnerBundle.putString("sourceLanguage", mSourceLanguage + " ["+ sourceCode + "]");
    spinnerBundle.putString("sourceCode", sourceCode);
    spinnerBundle.putString("destinationLanguage", mDestinationLanguage + " [" + destCode + "]");
    spinnerBundle.putString("destinationCode", getCode(mDestinationLanguage));

    intent.putExtras(spinnerBundle);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.finish();
}

// moze da mi treba pokasno za polnenje na spinner-ite
private ArrayAdapter<String> initializeSpinner(ArrayList<Language> lang){
    ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Language l: lang){
        entries.add(l.getLanguageName());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,entries);
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    return spinnerAdapter;
}

private void updateSpinners(){
    GoogleRequest gr = new GoogleRequest();
    try {
        String result = gr.requestLanguages("en");
        languages = gr.getLanguagesFromJSONObject(result);
        sourceSpinner.setAdapter(initializeSpinner(languages));
        destinationSpinner.setAdapter(initializeSpinner(languages));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "Empty spinners.. NO DATA...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private String getCode(String s){
    String ss="xx";
    for (Language l : languages){
        if(l.getLanguageName().toString()==s)
            ss = l.getLanguageCode().toString();
    }
    return ss;
}
```

}

and the GoogleRequest class...

```
public class GoogleRequest {

private final String requestURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=";
private final String requestURLLang = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?key=";
private final String requestKey = "**************";
private final String requestSrc = "&source=";
private final String requestDst = "&target=";
private final String requestTxt = "&q=";


public String requestLanguages(String target){
    String request = requestURLLang + requestKey + requestDst + target;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(request);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" );
        BufferedReader in =  new BufferedReader( inputStreamReader, 512 );
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ( ( line = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
            sb.append( line );
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String requestTranslation( String txt, String src, String dst ) {

    String request = requestURL + requestKey + requestSrc + src + requestDst + dst + requestTxt;   
    try {
        request += URLEncoder.encode( txt, "UTF-8" );
        URL url = new URL(request);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" );
        BufferedReader in =  new BufferedReader( inputStreamReader, 512 );
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ( ( line = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
            sb.append( line );
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } 
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getTextFromJSONObject(String text){

    try{
        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(text);
        JSONObject data = mainObj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray translations = data.getJSONArray("translations");

        String result = "";
        for(int i=0; i <translations.length(); i++){
            JSONObject translatedText = translations.getJSONObject(i);
            result += translatedText.getString("translatedText");
        }

        return result;
    }catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(null, "Parsing error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Language> getLanguagesFromJSONObject(String text){
    ArrayList<Language> googleLanguages = new ArrayList<Language>();

    try {
        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(text);
        JSONObject data = mainObj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray languages = data.getJSONArray("languages");


        for(int i=0; i<languages.length(); i++){
            Language l = new Language();
            JSONObject language = languages.getJSONObject(i);
            l.setLanuguageCode(language.getString("language"));
            l.setLanuguageName(language.getString("name"));

            googleLanguages.add(l);
        }

        return googleLanguages;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(null, "Parsing error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
}

public String printLista(ArrayList<Language> l){
    String s="";
    for(Language la: l){
        s+= la.getLanguageName().toString() + " [" + la.getLanguageCode().toString() + "]";
    }
    return s;
}}
```

the Options Layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".OptionsActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.98"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_choose_source"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:prompt="@string/label_choose_source"
        android:entries="@array/spinner1_entries"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_choose_destination"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/spinner1_entries"
        android:prompt="@string/label_choose_destination" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="submitLanguages"
    android:text="@string/button_submit_languages" />
```

and the LogCat:

```
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.textshottranslator/com.example.textshottranslator.OptionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1976)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1163)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4444)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:154)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at com.example.textshottranslator.GoogleRequest.getLanguagesFromJSONObject(GoogleRequest.java:99)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at com.example.textshottranslator.OptionsActivity.updateSpinners(OptionsActivity.java:76)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at com.example.textshottranslator.OptionsActivity.onCreate(OptionsActivity.java:27)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4494)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1940)
02-10 06:01:49.941: E/AndroidRuntime(10653):    ... 11 more
```

the LogCat looks like that when updateSpinners() method is modified like this:

```
private void updateSpinners(){
    GoogleRequest gr = new GoogleRequest();
    String result = gr.requestLanguages("en");
    languages = gr.getLanguagesFromJSONObject(result);
    sourceSpinner.setAdapter(initializeSpinner(languages));
    destinationSpinner.setAdapter(initializeSpinner(languages));
    try {

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Toast.makeText(this, "THIS IS IRRELEVANT NOW ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Post your full code and the accompanying LogCat stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use AsyncTask here's a link http://steveliles.github.com/android_s_asynctask.html may be this can help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is because you are not using a `AsyncTask` to get that data.

Comment: I really don't know how  works `AsyncTask` but if you think that is possible that can u send me some good tutorial? Thanks